# load multiple products with sort order of array of ids given

Tags: magento-1.9, products, multiple

I have loaded multiple products in magento with ids.following is my query

```
$productIds = array(1,5,3,10,6);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```

now my products are loaded in the sorting order of the product ids which i have in the `$productIds`. ie `product with id 1,3,5,6,10`.

but i want products to be loaded in the order of ids present in the `$productIds array`. ie `product with id 1,5,3,10,6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i tried in custom collection hope work for you.

```
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(entity_id, ' . implode(',', $productIds).')'));
```

Comment: Hi, the code is working and sorted product collection by given ids, but while reindexing it return syntax error on frontend. Is there any other way to sort?